# Is there anything I need to know about my son's uncircumcised penis?

Tags: health, hygiene, sex

My son is very young, so this information is for the future.

I'm a circumcised male, I know pretty well how everything works down there.

Is there any information that should be given to uncircumcised boys when it comes time for The Talk about sex and sexuality?

(Evidence-based advice for healthy sexuality is what I have in mind here.)

Comment: Aside from specific cleaning required for an uncircumcised previous, no, there is going to be nothing you need to discuss that is different to what you would talk about for a circumcised boy as regards sex.

Comment: At some point you are probably going to have to explain why you are different from him, so you might think that one through ahead of time.

Comment: @RoryAlsop - If this is true, why is circumcision being encouraged to decrease HIV and other STI's in Africa? Should a father not talk about the increased incidence of STI's with his about-to-become-sexually-active son?

Comment: @anongoodnurse - I'll try and pull out the research papers I saw that seemed to debunk this a bit.

Answer (score 3):

No, there are nothing special you need to do or talk about.

The skin protects the head, and since children don't produce so much testosterone, they don't produce so much sebum (grease) from the sebaceous glands, so there are no o need to clean under the skin untill they hit puberty.

Some can't even withdraw the skin at young age, but that usually solves it self when he grows older (*it was suppose to work so by design*).

As older and sex, there are no big difference between cut and uncut.

Basically you can say it's like a clicker-pen, it peeks out when it need to.

Health wise it better because it gives more protection against urinary infection.

The sebum is also protecting against fungus and bacteria.

The disadvantage is that since the head don't get cleaned against the undies, as the cut one does, it requires cleaning (after puberty), but it's just to clean it during shower/bath, and there is nothing special, just water and soap..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When claims are made on most SE sites like "Health wise it better because it gives more protection against urinary infection." they need to be backed up with a reliable source. Thanks.

Comment: It's basics, if the urethra is covered with skin, the e-coli, which comes from faeces, are having a harder time to get in. However, those who support circumcision, always claims it's better.

Comment: "It's basic" can be applied to every manner of misconception. I've never hospitalized or treated a circumcised adult male for [balanitis or balanoposthitis](https://www.uptodate.com/contents/balanitis-and-balanoposthitis-in-children-and-adolescents-clinical-manifestations-evaluation-and-diagnosis). By your logic, uncircumcised males should have a lower prevalence of STIs (e.g. HIV); in fact, the opposite is true. Your opinion is not "a reliable source". You made two medical claims which you need to support.

Comment: you generally shouldn't use soap. From memory there is an increase in UTIs in uncircumcised children, but it's about the same number of cases as there are complications related to circumcision.